# Differentiability in functions of several variables

Tags: analysis

$f$ and $g$ are functions from $D \subseteq R^n \rightarrow{R}$ and $x_0$ is in D

Let be $f$ and $g$ be differenciable at $x_0$. Prove that the product $fg$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and  $d(fg)(x_0)=f(x_0)dg(x_0)+g(x_0)df(x_0)$. The hint is use the proof for $n=1$, I saw it and in a variable
is to add and subtract $f (x) g (x) + h (x)$ but I don't know how to apply in several variables. Thanks

Comment: The routine which is this proof is nicely written [here](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/spivak-calc-manifolds.pdf#page=35). The relevant part is left to the reader, but it is clear that they want you to apply the chain rule with the computation of the differential of $p(x,y)=xy$ done in Theorem 2-3 part (5).

Comment: Note that in order to talk about differentiability of some function at $x_0 \in D$, $x_0$ must be in the interior of $D$.